# PHP XML double quote

Tags: php, xml, curl

I try to send string with xml content via curl post request to test.php.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SMS-InsRequest>
<CLIENT user="test" pwd="demo" from="5555" />
    <INSERTMSG text="Hi &quot;John&quot;. API test1 date: 24.07.2013"></INSERTMSG>
</SMS-InsRequest>
```

Where **test.php** just receive request:

```
simplexml_load_string($_POST['xml_request'])
```

But I get error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <INSERTMSG text="Hi  in /var/www/html/xml/test.php on line 68
```

why request come with double quotes instead of `&quot;`, as I write?
For example, when I send that xml via Delphi, **test.php** is running correct.

Thanks.

Comment: try simplexml_load_string(htmlentities($_POST['xml_request']));

Comment: I also try htmlspecialchars and htmlentities: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/html/xml/test.php on line 19

Comment: That works for me http://3v4l.org/gdVki

Comment: simplexml_load_string(html_entity_decode($_POST['xml_request'], ENT_QUOTES));

Comment: @Vladimir Hraban< for me also work. Problem is start when I run send via browser